# Adobe Flash CS5 Paintbrush and Pencil are objects?

Tags: flash, adobe, drawing, flash-cs5

I was doing some drawing in Flash CS5, and then all of a sudden, the paintbrush starts having a purple square around it instead of dots inside.  I also noticed that the pencil tool did it too.  I obviously accidentally switched an option somewhere on accident.  How do I switch it back?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you accidentally toggled the "object" drawing mode.

Check out the explanation here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7e87a.html  The article also mentions how to turn it on/off.

I remember being befuddled the first time I accidentally toggled it too.